# react native "yarn ios" command hangs on forever

Tags: ruby, xcode, react-native

when i run "yarn ios" command in my terminal it does not progress even if i wait a long time

! "Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): >=2.6.10." is already there. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUfp7.png)

i tried "bundle install" and "bundle exec pod install" to ios folder then i tried to open ".xcworkspace" file to build app but this time xcode didn't open it again it hanged on forever.

How can i overcome with this problem?